# Grab full text with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm using beautiful soup and I want to scrape a simple webpage.

This [Page](https://spys.one/en/https-ssl-proxy/) provides many free proxy and I want to grab them and save the inside a list.

As you know a proxy is looking like this: `IP:PORT` and this site provide their proxies too, so I can get ip addresses but I couldn't get port!

Here is my part of code that worked properly and get ips and save them into a list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
    
HEADER = {"ACCEPT-LANGUAGE": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
          "USER-AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                        "Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"}
    
response = requests.get(url="https://spys.one/en/https-ssl-proxy", headers=HEADER)
response.raise_for_status()
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    
all_ips = soup.find_all("font", attrs={"class": "spy14"})
ips = [ip for data in all_ips for ip in data if "." in ip and "(" not in ip]
```

Here is the output of above script:

```
 ['45.181.207.1', '67.55.186.177', '107.178.9.186', '173.208.140.122', '217.23.55.52', '181.225.54.59', '23.237.173.101', '190.214.27.106', '162.207.65.69', '79.119.155.137', '209.40.237.43', '74.113.137.156', '91.126.189.227', '211.24.105.19', '92.207.253.226', '103.81.77.11', '65.121.180.14', '157.90.103.34', '200.124.226.166', '103.21.160.10', '85.99.120.94', '49.49.23.252', '124.106.230.55', '79.101.67.154', '95.0.6.228', '190.13.82.102', '175.101.27.162', '208.127.25.69', '103.7.27.186', '124.217.246.133']
```

But the problem is I can't get Port numbers to combine them with their relevant ips!

Here is part of the html page that I want to grab data:

```
<td colspan="1">
    <font class="spy14">
        43.250.126.1
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write("<font class=spy2>:<\/font>" + (N5FS ^ ONE5N) + (NETZ ^ Z5O) + (NETZ ^ Z5O) + (NFEN ^ N5V))
        </script>
    </font>
</td>
```

You see, the port number in chrome developer tools is just a simple text like itd ip, but here in plain html there is no port number (Actually this jumbo mumbo javascript is relevant port number I guess)

So please look at [this](https://spys.one/en/https-ssl-proxy/) page and help me out to get the port numbers too!

Comment: The port numbers are applied to the HTML with Javascript. I suggest you use **selenium** for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Port number is being loaded by JavaScript. To get that data you have to use selenium.

Here is how selenium is used to get the Proxies list (with Port numbers included)

```py
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=options)

url_req = "https://spys.one/en/https-ssl-proxy/"
driver.get(url_req)
time.sleep(5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

driver.close()

trs = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': ['spy1x', 'spy1xx']})
for i in trs[1:]:
    print(i.select_one('td').text.strip())
```

Sample Output:

```
65.121.180.14:21988
139.162.20.252:8080
103.250.153.203:8080
190.145.200.126:53281
5.63.162.174:8080
45.190.13.50:999
34.122.246.161:3128
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all instead of this complex code

```
all_ips = soup.find_all("font", attrs={"class": "spy14"})
ips = [ip for data in all_ips for ip in data if "." in ip and "(" not in ip]
```

You can simply use this:

```
all_ips = soup.select('tr>td:nth-of-type(1)>font.spy14')
```

This will give you all the IP addresses.
As about getting the ports....
I really don't know why this data is not received with the IP addresses, it's strange.

Comment: Hey, for me this(all_ips = soup.find_all('tr>td:nth-of-type(1)>font.spy14')) returns an empty list

Comment: You are right, sorry. It should be `select` there instead of `find` since `select` supports css selectors while `find` doesn't. I have updated the answer as well

Comment: Thanks! that works but i have a question: where that "tr>td:nth-of-type(1)>font.spy14" comes from?

Comment: I inspected those fields (elements) with dev tools to see the css selector matching those elements. You should improve your knowledge about correct XPath and CSS Selectors. There are several good tutorials for that. Just google for "css selector best practices" or similar

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using **selenium**. I take no credit for the RE. I got that [here](https://www.regextester.com/97040)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re

ipa = re.compile(
    '^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]):[0-9]+$')

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')  
with webdriver.Firefox(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get('https://spys.one/en/https-ssl-proxy/')
    for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//font[@class="spy14"]'):
        if ipa.match(element.text):
            print(element.text)
```